# illegal argument exception in url

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

> i want to request wfc service by using url and i add three parameter in url it was error in run time illegal argument exception

```
String myUrl;
    myUrl = String.format("http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/? Location=%s&GROUP=%s&asondate=%s",items,items1,finalDate);
```

> logcat

```
07-03 10:04:31.602: E/AndroidRuntime(2790): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
  ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.innovate/com.androidhive.innovate.AndroidJSONParsingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 49: http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/? Location=ArihantWanarpet&GROUP=ArihantShowroom&asondate=2013-07-03
```

Comment: Check the Portno 51382 and also spaces in your url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a space in your URL, after the `?`. Get rid of it, and I suspect you'll fine all is well. So this:

```
"http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/? Location=%s&GROUP=%s&asondate=%s"
```

becomes

```
"http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/?Location=%s&GROUP=%s&asondate=%s"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:
 [image]

OR

```
String myUrl;
myUrl = String.format("http://10.0.2.2:51382/RestServiceImpl.svc/jsons/? Location=%s&GROUP=%s&asondate=%s",items,items1,finalDate);
String url = URLEncoder.encode(myUrl, utf-8); 
System.out.println(url);
```